# trying to return the result of sp_executesql and getting "A RETURN statement with a return value cannot be used in this context"

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to use dynamic SQL w/in a function so that I can do things like `SELECT * FROM searchAllFields('Pregnant')`. I know that it is not possible to use dynamic SQL within a function but I see that this guy has found a workaround [Getting an error when executing a dynamic sql within a function (SQL Server)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15180561/getting-an-error-when-executing-a-dynamic-sql-within-a-function-sql-server)

But when I try applying his work around on mycode I get `A RETURN statement with a return value cannot be used in this context.` It seems like I am doing the exact same thing. Why am I getting that error in my code?

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[searchTerm](@search nvarchar(max))
as
begin
declare @value nvarchar(500),
        @SQLString nvarchar(4000),
        @stmt nvarchar(max)

select @stmt = isnull(@stmt + ' or ', '') + quotename(name) + ' like @search'
from sys.columns as c
where c.[object_id] = object_id('dbo.table')

select @stmt = 'select @value = id from table where ' + @stmt

exec sp_executesql
    @stmt = @stmt,
    @params = N'@search nvarchar(max)',
    @search = @search,
    @value = @value output

    return @value 
end
```

Comment: The accepted answer in the linked question is using a stored procedure, not a function.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson good point. I changed mine to a SP but got the same error.

Comment: How are you using this SP? You can not do a select form a stored procedure. You have to execute it and this procedure does not return a resultset. If you actually tested the SP you have posted here I would guess that you get the error `Must declare the scalar variable "@value".`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this isn't going to work as your function returns an [inline table-valued function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx#code-snippet-2).

For this syntax the function definition is followed by `AS RETURN ( SELECT ...  )` rather than `AS BEGIN... RETURN ... END`