# SQL Server execute (sp_executesql ) command in SQL function

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-function

I created a function in SQL Server to execute a dynamic SQL query and return a value. I'm getting error when calling function in SQL query:

> Only functions and some extended stored procedures can be executed from within a function

Function: (return number of users associated with @ModuleName)

```
DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Result int
DECLARE @UsersUsingModule AS NVARCHAR(99)

SET @Query = 'SELECT @UsersUsingModule = Count(UR.UserId) '+
        'FROM       '+@UserDBName+'.[dbo].[aspnet_UsersInRoles] AS UR '+
        'INNER JOIN '+@UserDBName+'.[dbo].[aspnet_Roles] AS R ON UR.RoleId = R.RoleId '+
        'INNER JOIN '+@UserDBName+'.[dbo].[aspnet_Users] AS U ON UR.UserId = U.UserId '+
        'WHERE      LOWER(RoleName) IN ( '+
            'SELECT LOWER([Role]) '+
            'FROM   ADMIN_ROLEACCESS '+
            'WHERE  LOWER(ModuleName) = LOWER(@ModuleName) '+
        ')'

        EXEC sp_executesql @Query, N'@ModuleName nvarchar(max), @UsersUsingModule INT OUTPUT', @ModuleName, @UsersUsingModule OUTPUT

SELECT @Result =  CAST(@UsersUsingModule as INT)
RETURN @Result
```

Query:

```
SELECT      
    M.ID as [ModuleID], M.ModuleName, CC.UserLicenses,
    dbo.fncRolesWithModule(M.ModuleName) AS [Roles],
    [dbo].[fncUsersUsingModule](M.ModuleName, 'USERS_Demo2016')
FROM        
    ADMIN_ClientsContracts as CC
INNER JOIN  
    ADMIN_Modules as M ON CC.ModuleID = M.ID
WHERE
    CC.Isactive = 1
```

Advice me if there is any better approach!

Comment: Have a look at (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15180561/getting-an-error-when-executing-a-dynamic-sql-within-a-function-sql-server,'this'). Might help :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Functions are used for calculations, something like a `SELECT` query. You can't execute stored procedures inside a function. In this case you are trying to use the procedure `sp_executesql` inside the function and that is causing this issue.

If you wanted to perform the same steps, instead of functions you can use a procedure like below.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetUserModule
@UserDBName NVARCHAR(50),
@ModuleName NVARCHAR(150)

AS

BEGIN

DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Result int
DECLARE @UsersUsingModule AS NVARCHAR(99)

SET @Query = 'SELECT @UsersUsingModule = Count(UR.UserId) '+
        'FROM       '+@UserDBName+'.[dbo].[aspnet_UsersInRoles] AS UR '+
        'INNER JOIN '+@UserDBName+'.[dbo].[aspnet_Roles] AS R ON UR.RoleId = R.RoleId '+
        'INNER JOIN '+@UserDBName+'.[dbo].[aspnet_Users] AS U ON UR.UserId = U.UserId '+
        'WHERE      LOWER(RoleName) IN ( '+
            'SELECT LOWER([Role]) '+
            'FROM   ADMIN_ROLEACCESS '+
            'WHERE  LOWER(ModuleName) = LOWER(@ModuleName) '+
        ')'

        EXEC sp_executesql @Query, N'@ModuleName nvarchar(max), @UsersUsingModule INT OUTPUT'
                           , @ModuleName
                           , @UsersUsingModule OUTPUT

        SELECT @Result =  CAST(@UsersUsingModule as INT)
    RETURN @Result

END
```

Answer (score 5):

By definition, a **FUNCTION** is never allowed to ALTER table contents. Here in this it is just a SELECT, I understand but IMHO FUNCTION's aren't designed for that. **STORED PROCEDURES** are designed to do that trick.

If you still want to proceed with doing what you intend to do, then you might have to use some hacks as mentioned in [this](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/denis_gobo/archive/2008/05/08/6703.aspx) site, which aren't advisable at all on a longer run.

You can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344880/execute-stored-procedure-from-a-function) question for a similar discussion!

Hope this helps!